# Broken .searchable() modifier in SwiftUI with Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ipados, xcode14

I noticed that when I create a simple searchable list in my old iPadOS/iOS App with the latest Xcode 14 Beta (at least beta no 4 and 5), the text deletes itself. I'm not sure if this happened with old versions of Xcode and iPadOS Betas (just noticed with iPadOS beta 4 and 5, too).

I created a new project with just this few lines of code:

```
@main
struct MyApp: SwiftUI.App {
    
@State private var strings = ""
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack {
                List {
                    Text("Item 1")
                    Text("Item 2")
                    Text("Item 3")
                }
                .searchable(text: $strings)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I build and execute this in a new project, it works properly. BUT if I try to execute that exact code in my old app (created with Xcode 11) I get this:

[image]

As we can see, once I write a single letter in the SearchTextField, it deletes itself. I cannot debug this, because this is all the code my app is running, and I cannot send to Apple any Feedback because when I create a new project it works correctly.

Does anyone know if this error happens because an incorrect configuration or something similar?

[iPad Pro 12.9, Swift 5.6, SwiftUI 4.0, Xcode 14 Beta 5]

Comment: Try making your list based off of any array of data instead of a static list of 3 items. When you do that, you should be able to search.

Comment: Same result, because the problem is not the content of the listo, the problem is than the SearchField deletes its content independently from the content of the List (even if is a Vstack)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

The problem was caused because a `Binding` extension, added to extend some features to SwiftUI. This is the snippet that was causing the issue (please, DO NOT USE this snippet):

```
extension Binding: Equatable where Value: Equatable {
    public static func == (lhs: Binding<Value>, rhs: Binding<Value>) -> Bool {
        return lhs.wrappedValue == rhs.wrappedValue
    }
}

extension Binding: Hashable where Value: Hashable {
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        self.wrappedValue.hash(into: &hasher)
    }
}
```

I had a lot of work searching over the more than 50.000 lines of code of my app, created a new target and added manually files to inspect what was causing the error. I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

See my example below:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var searchText = ""
    let strings: [String] = ["1", "2", "3"]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            List(strings, id: \.self) {
                Text($0)
            }.searchable(text: $searchText)
        }
    }
}
```

This issue either has to do with the custom `NavigationStack` you are using or the lack of a list. Without more details it would be impossible to tell. I would suggest working backwards to a state that works and then move forward one item at a time to see where it breaks. My example above works to have a search bar and a list of items (no filter functionality yet though).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm getting the same result using `NavigationView`. The text inside the SearchTextField deletes itself when `searchText.count > 1`.